# how can i change the params of videoview in android?

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

how can I change the layout params (centerInParent) of a videoview

```
<VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false" />
```

to

```
<VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

regards
christian

Answer (score 0):

Did You mean, setting LayoutParams programmatically? Maybe it is possible with a code like this

```
    RelativeLayout.Layoutparams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
```